# If I send a python 'Signal' object from a function, what should the "sender" argument be?

Tags: python, django, signals

If I send a Signal from a module function (a django view function as it happens), that is not inside a Class, it's not obvious (to me) what the sender should be - if anything? Is `sender=None` appropriate in this case?

Alternatively, the function is invoked by an HTTP request, which I currently pass in as a separate argument - should I pass that instead?

Option A:

```
from django.dispatch import Signal
my_signal = Signal(
    providing_args=['my_arg', 'request']
)    

# this is a view function
def do_something(request):
    # ... do useful stuff
    my_signal.send(
        sender=None,
        my_arg="Hello",
        request=request
    )
```

Option B:

```
from django.dispatch import Signal
my_signal = Signal(
    providing_args=['my_arg']
)    

# this is a view function
def do_something(request):
    # ... do useful stuff
    my_signal.send(
        sender=request,
        my_arg="Hello",
    )
```

**[UPDATE]**

Option A has it. There's nothing useful that the receiver can do with the sender in this case (i.e. it's not an object), so set it to None.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The django.dispatch.Dispatcher [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py#L159) simply says it should be

```
"...[t]he sender of the signal. Either a specific object or None."
```

which then ties in with the receiver via [connect()](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py#L67), for which the sender's significance is:

```
"The sender to which the receiver should respond. Must either be
 of type Signal, or None to receive events from any sender"
```

which, I admit, isn't particularly clear, but in your case, I would say to use `sender=None` because there's nothing concrete to hook to, as the request is transient.

Answer (score 0):

A function is an object in Python, so you can just set the sender to be a reference your function, like this:

```
def my_func():
    my_signal.send(sender=my_func, my_arg="Hello")
```